# How do I seperate 500k images from single directory to multiple?

Tags: php, directory

I do have 500k images in one directory. Name of these images are stored in MySQL database. I want to divide this 500k images into 10k each directories. like 10k images in img01, another 10k images in img02,..etc. How can I do this with a PHP program?? does any one can help me with a sample code so I can modify it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about a sample code by you and we can help you modify it? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will just show a pseudo-code approach, and if you are still stuck you can show what you tried and where you are stuck.

```
Select all images

Loop through the result

  if cntr mod 10k == 0 then 
    make new directory 
  else 
    use last directory

  Move the file to the new directory.

end loop
```

Then loop through each directory, updating the location in your database.

Now, another approach is to read everything in, then do the update in the loop, depending on memory availability.

Comment: I thought the pseudo code would be easier to read with a little formatting.  Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it :)

Comment: @Mark Biek - Oops, I forgot to include numbers next to them, but your formatting looks nice. Thank you, I just have one minor fix to your improvement.